# Как сделать canvas фоном дива

Tags: html, javascript, css

Скажите, как сделать изображение на `canvas` фоном элемента?

Answer (score 5):

Если все же нужно использовать канву как фон, можно воспользоваться этим способом:

```js
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
ctx.fillRect(10,10,10,90)
ctx.fillRect(10,50,90,10)
ctx.fillRect(90,10,10,90)
document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${canvas.toDataURL()}`;
```

```css
body{width:100%;height:100%}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=100 height=100 style=display:none></canvas>
```

Comment: @Дмытрык вопрошающего явно уже ничего не интересует, сообщение писал для сообщества, в основном потому что единственный ответ - так себе

Comment: А почему `position: absolute` не нравится?

Comment: @МихаилКамахин мне всё нравится, пользуйся)

Answer (score 4):

абсолютом его разместить.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы так сделал

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
resizeCtxCanvas(ctx);

function resizeCtxCanvas(ctx) {
  const { width, height } = ctx.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  ctx.canvas.width = width;
  ctx.canvas.height = height;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  drawCanvas(ctx);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', e => {
  resizeCtxCanvas(ctx);
});

function drawCanvas(ctx) {
  const canvas = ctx.canvas;
    
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#bcbcbc";
  ctx.strokeWidth = 5;
  for (let y = 0; y < canvas.height; y += 96) {
    for (let x = 0; x < canvas.width; x += 96) {
      ctx.rect(x, y, 96, 96);
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.parentCanvas {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.parentCanvas .canvas {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

p {
  font-size: 10vmax;
}
```

```html
<h1>Блок с канвасом на фоне ниже</h1>

<div class="parentCanvas">
  <canvas id="canvas" class="canvas"></canvas>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod numquam blanditiis esse iste minima, excepturi dolor earum suscip
  </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `canvas.toDataURL()`

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("stars");
// Draw on canvas here
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(\"" + canvas.toDataURL() + "\"";
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="background-repeat: no-repeat;">
<canvas id="stars" style="display: none;"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ниже точно такой же ответ. (-)